# iOS/Obj-C - Implement UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete on one tableview in View Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have three tableviews inside of one View Controller (their visibility is controlled by a segment control). That said, I only want cells to have the option of being deleted from self.friendsView, and not the other tableviews. I have the following code below in my View Controller, but the ability to swipe and delete a cell is visible on all three of my tableviews, not just self.friendsView. How can I fix this?

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.friendsView) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            // Delete the row from the data source

            NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [[self.myFriendData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] mutableCopy];

            NSString *nid = [nodeData objectForKey:@"nid"];
            [nodeData setObject:nid forKey:@"nid"];
            NSLog(@"%@",nid);

            [self.myFriendData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];



            [DIOSNode nodeDelete:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"node deleted!");
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"could not delete node!");
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but why do you have three table views when only one is visible at a time? Just have one table view. When the user selects a different segment you reload the one table view. Your data source methods return the proper data based on the selected segment. Far more efficient than having three separate table views and having to hide/show them as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to implementing `commitEditingStyle` you also need to implement the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.friendsView) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```